# What is the most idiomatic way to use the Node cluster module?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, load-balancing

Node cluster presents a convenient way to fork child processes to balance server loads, which follows the philosophy of traditional fork() system calls in most operating systems. In the official cluster documentation page, the sample code demonstrates how a master server differs from its worker servers, so far so good since all code resides in the same file. But in real life projects, I found the documentation not detailed enough for users to apply the module in different situations, for example,

- What does the "server" mean in `server.listen()`? Just an HTTP server?
- How should developer fork only part of the code of interest as child processes which would run in the same process with any other code? 
  (Worse still, the child processes might have state dependencies shared between worker processes and master process?)
- How do worker processes communicate over arbitrary data with each other?
- What's the best way to separate the code run in child processes from master process, or is it really necessary?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js [Cluster API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) provide good examples.

The short answer is the Server.listen() is a Node http server. The Cluster module is using the child_process.fork() method, and then via IPC keeps the workers in sync.

In this example from the docs, notice how the master never calls `server.listen()`

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case its a HTTP server
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

Comment: What actually confused me was that this lovely piece of code didn't work on Windows. The node documentation says that Windows doesn't support named pipes on IPC. So, how could I possibly utilize the cluster module on Windows machines?